# Updating all rows of a particular column in every table of a specific database (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql-update, concatenation

I am trying to update all rows of a column in every table in my database. My current SQL looks as follows:

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE `', a.table_name, '` SET columnName = NULL;')
FROM information_schema.tables a
WHERE a.table_schema = 'databaseName'
```

When I run this command, I get the series of commands running such as:

```
UPDATE `Friday` SET columnName = NULL;
```

Friday is one of the tables in the database I specified. The issue is that when I run this, no changes are made to the tables themselves. If I were to take one of the commands that my concatenation outputted and run it, the table is then affected. I am somewhat new to using MySQL so why a concatenated series of commands versus a single command run change the effects? Is my initial command formatted incorrectly for what I am trying to achieve? Thanks for any help!

Edit: Following the comments and the documentation that was posted, here is an update to where I am at.

```
SET @s:='';
SELECT @s:=concat(@s, 'UPDATE TABLE ', a.TABLE_SCHEMA,'.`',  a.TABLE_NAME, '` SET columnName = NULL;') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES a where table_schema = 'databaseName';    
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Just read the documentation closer and saw that prepared statements do not work on multiple statements. Looking into procedures.

Edit:

Here's a bit closer to what I am trying to accomplish. Still, have a few errors I need to work through.

```
    DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myproc $$

CREATE PROCEDURE myproc() 
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

DECLARE done tinyint(1) DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE sql2 VARCHAR(2000);

DECLARE csr CURSOR FOR 
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE `',c.table_schema,'`.`',c.table_name,'` SET `columnName` = NULL') AS sql2
    FROM information_schema.columns c
   WHERE c.column_name = 'columnName'
     AND c.table_schema IN ('databaseName');
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN csr;
  do_foo: LOOP
     FETCH csr INTO sql2;
     IF done THEN
        LEAVE do_foo;
     END IF;
     PREPARE stmt FROM sql2;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP do_foo;
  CLOSE csr;

  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Its not at all clear what behavior is being observed. Saying "no changes are made to the tables" and "table is then affected" is practically useless in determining what client is being used; what mechanism is being used to take the resultset from SELECT, and executing those strings as SQL statements. Running that SELECT statement just returns a resultset. It matters not one whit what the result of the CONCAT expression is; that it happens to look like SQL text doesn;t make any difference. (The SELECT is just returning a column of datatype  VARCHAR.)

Comment: To reiterate, when you submit the SELECT statement to MySQL server for execution, the statement completes successfully, and MySQL server returns a resultset. Normally, the client fetches rows from the resultset and displays them as text ala mysql command line client. (As far as the client is concerned, what is returned is not "a series of commands". What is returned is a resultset, like a table, a set or rows consisting of a single column of datatype VARCHAR.)

Comment: @spencer7593 Ah sorry new to using MySQL. Yes, then a resultset is returned when using the sql snippet I posted. I was under the assumption that it would run them similarly to a normal sql statement. How should I go about running each result in the resultset?

Comment: My end goal is to run all of these statements in a scheduled event. Is there a way to loop through the resultlist and execute each statement in a mysql event?

Comment: I suspect you need to create your update statements and submit them to mysql see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html. AND to loop through all the tables put the code into a stored procedure. BTW do you really have a column called columnname in all the tables you wish to update?

Comment: @P.Salmon I do not, no. When I first wrote the question I was testing the statement on a test database. In that database, I have a test table with a column columnName.  I'll check out the docs you posted. Thanks.

Comment: @spencer7593 Took your advice and slowly getting to what I think you meant by your first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. Thanks for those who commented and pointed me in the right direction. If anyone needs to update every column in a database in the future, here's what I did:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myproc $$

CREATE PROCEDURE myproc() 
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

DECLARE done tinyint(1) DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE sql2 VARCHAR(2000);

DECLARE csr CURSOR FOR 
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE ',c.table_schema,'.`',c.table_name,'` SET columnName = NULL') AS sql2
    FROM information_schema.columns c
   WHERE c.column_name = 'columnName'
     AND c.table_schema IN ('databaseName');
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN csr;
  do_foo: LOOP
     FETCH csr INTO sql2;
     IF done THEN
        LEAVE do_foo;
     END IF;

     SET @newTest = sql2;
     PREPARE stmt FROM @newTest;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP do_foo;
  CLOSE csr;

  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```